# Как проверить n ссылок?

Tags: python, алгоритм, веб-программирование, поиск

Условно есть `n` (большое кол-во) ссылок, одна из них содержит страницу с паролем, остальные же не содержат ничего. Ссылки находятся на одном сайте, но имеют разные порты.

Пример:

```
site.com:1000 ... site.com:5000
```

Как найти нужный сайт?

Comment: Ну как бы перебором только и найти...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывести все нужные порты через цикл и просканировать их.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые ответы) В данном случае очень не помешал бы кусочек кода который делает то, что описано в вопросе)